# Scaling an image sequence

Tags: ios

I have tried to scale a UIImageView that is running an image sequence using `imageView.animationImages` and calling `[self.imageView startAnimating];`

```
- (void) updateViewSizeWithScale:(float) scale
{
    // calculate the new size based on the scale
    int newSize = originalSize * scale;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x, self.imageView.frame.origin.y, newSize, newSize);
       } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

This does not scale the UIImageView as while the animating images are running. I have tried to set the self.frame in the animation block (self is a UIView subclass) but it does not scale the imageview.

What would be the best way to run a sequence of images inside a container view and scale the container so that the images scale while the sequence is running?

Should I use layers or a lower level API?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday, and it worked after setting two things:

```
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES; 
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: great. I will try this tomorrow. Thanks. Otherwise cocos2d :P

Answer (score 0):

Consider using CGAffine Transformation to do the job:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
  CGAffineTransform newScale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
  CGAffineTransform newTranslate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(10.0, 10.0);

  self.myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(newScale, newTranslate);
  } 
  completion:^(BOOL finished) {

 }
];
```

Comment: I had a problem with this that the image size increased as the frame rotated.